# Php posting file to ServiceStack API

Tags: php, curl, upload, servicestack

I need help posting a file (doc, Docx, or pdf) to a ServiceStack API using PHP.

php cURL setup:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$cfile = new CURLFile('C:\\test.doc');
$params = array('Data' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
```

API setup:

```
 public object Any([FromBody]ExampleRequest exampleRequest){
...
}

public class ExampleRequest : IReturn<ExampleResponse>
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }
```

With a property called Data of type object inside ExampleRequest

I'm not sure why Data will always be null. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please update your question to show the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers and the `ExampleRequest` DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[FromBody]` is not a ServiceStack Attribute and has no effect in ServiceStack Services.

Your Typed Request DTO needs to simply match the schema of the `ExampleRequest`. All ServiceStack Services can be populated by [QueryString, FormData, or via Request Body](https://docs.servicestack.net/architecture-overview) in any of the [default registered Content-Types](https://docs.servicestack.net/formats) like JSON. You need to ensure your Request is sending the correct format that matches its `Content-Type` HTTP Request Header.

It's recommended that you never use `object` otherwise you need to account for the [custom serialization behavior and security restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#late-bound-object-and-interface-runtime-types) for deserializing `object` types.

By defining a `Data` property, you're telling ServiceStack to accept requests with a **Data** property like (e.g. JSON):

```
{"Data": ...}
```

> If sending flat Key/Value pairs, consider using `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of `object`

#### Parsing the Raw Request Body yourself

Your Request DTO should specify the Type of the Schema, if you don't want to do that you can tell ServiceStack to skip deserializing the Request Body and have your Service parse the raw Request Body by having your [Request DTO implement IRequiresRequestStream](https://docs.servicestack.net/serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream), e.g:

```
//Request DTO
public class ExampleRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public object Any(ExampleRequest request)
{
    byte[] bytes = request.RequestStream.ReadFully();
    string text = bytes.FromUtf8Bytes(); //if text was sent
}
```